# ionic2 rc0 build error on ios device/simulator main.js

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I updated from ionic2 beta 11 to rc0.
Everything was working on beta 11, after creating a new project with rc0 I got the following errors:

```
[12:35:30]  bundle prod started ...
[12:35:30]  Error: Could not resolve entry (.tmp/app/main.prod.js)
at /Users/MAC/myapp/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:8602:28
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

[12:35:30]  sass started ...
[12:35:32]  sass finished in 2.28 s
[12:35:32]  minify started ...
[12:35:32]  cleancss started ...
[12:35:32]  uglifyjs started ...
[12:35:32]  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MAC/myapp/www/build/main.js'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
at addFile (/Users/MAC/myapp/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:68:22)
at /Users/MAC/myapp/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:79:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.exports.minify (/Users/MAC/myapp/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:77:26)
at runUglifyInternal (/Users/MAC/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/uglifyjs.js:34:19)
at runUglify (/Users/MAC/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/uglifyjs.js:23:28)
at Object.uglifyjs (/Users/MAC/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/uglifyjs.js:9:12)
```

I noticed that the problem is the main.js file is not being created.
Thank you

I got this error in safari web developer:

```
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/12824002-C5CC-42CD-8173-4A472DC68C9E/myapp.app/www/build/main.js
```

The contents of main.prod.js are:

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app.module.ngfactory';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by  re installing stuff.

```
$ npm install ionic@latest -g
$ npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

You can also refer [this discussion](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1420)